# US Citizen living abroad: Can I put a foreign address on I-9/W-4 forms, for tax return purposes?

Tags: united-states, income-tax-refund, form-w-4

I am US Citizen, currently living abroad and work for a company in the USA. I was asked to fill out the I-9 and W-4 forms and was wondering what address to list. my us or foreign address. Specifically concerned about having a problem filing for tax returns if I put a foreign address on my forms.

Comment: Hi Avi,

I'm having the same issue/question right now. What was your resolution?

For me, I tried putting on the W-4 my foreign address to indicate that I was truly abroad. Since it says residential address. However, that resulted in issues with the payroll system...which is still not resolved. I'm about to contact my accountant about what I should be putting in.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can find, if you are eligible you can fill out the form 673 instead of the w4, but waiting to hear from my tax advisor.  I'm in the same boat.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem putting a foreign address on a 1040, my wife has been doing it for 15 years.
I don't recall that she's been asked to file the forms you mention, though I imagine it's best to be consistent.